# why would someone write overflow: hidden on <html> tag

Tags: html, css

I was reading source code of an template and i got code

```
<html class="js" style="overflow: hidden">
```

My question is why would someone will apply `overflow:hidden` on html tag. what benefit it will give.`

Comment: I can't see the rule but possibly to clear floats.

Comment: @DennisFagan can you explain it with a fiddle.

Comment: I added an answer with a fiddle

Comment: @DennisFagan see the comment

Comment: Why not add the same property to body tag instead? What's the advantage you get by adding it to HTML tag?

Answer (score 3):

You would use `overflow:hidden` when you have dynamic, responsive content, for the most part, or at least, that is what I use it for. For example, if you have a page with content that grows in  height as you shrink the page, you may want to just hide whatever is not visible in the regular height of the div

Comment: I suspect the user knows that, but is wondering why it's on an `html` element.

Comment: @scrblnrd3 i know what overflow: hidden does. i just did not understood why someone will put it on html tag

Comment: @user3050499 Yup. That's what I thought :)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question

Comment: Why not add the same property to body tag instead? What's the advantage you get by adding it to HTML tag?

Answer (score 3):

It's most likely to remove all scroll bars.

When you set `overflow: hidden`, anything that is outside of the element is hidden, obviously. What this does when you attach it to the `html` element is hides everything that is not on the screen. The browser then sees that because everything that is not on the screen is hidden, there is nowhere to scroll to, so it hides the scroll bars.

Templates that want a clean, full browser look will remove scroll bars if they feel that there is nothing that the user should need to scroll to.

Comment: Why not add the same property to body tag instead? What's the advantage you get by adding it to HTML tag?

Comment: To my knowledge, you gain nothing and it can be on the body tag instead. `<html>` is more visible as it's the topmost level element, but `<body>` is more likely the topmost usable element to place this on. Personal preference at that point.

Answer (score 2):

Overflow hidden can be used to clear floats http://jsfiddle.net/PRwVT/1/ add

```
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 3px;
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

to overwrite the .wrapper class in that fiddle and you will see what I mean. That being said the only element that could have floats and be a direct child of the html element is the body tag.

Comment: No where related to my question. i mentioned it why someone will apply it on html element. Not on wrapper. i know how it will work in this case.

Comment: html element wraps everything. fiddle doesnt allow you to edit the html element. I agree it is weird.

Answer (score 1):

This disables the page from scrolling. So for example when you might open an overlay on a page and you would like to be able to scroll the overlay content but not scroll the page behind it at the same time.

In this case you might add a class onto the html element that sets 'overflow:hidden' when you click a button to open the modal, then remove that class when you click the close button on the modal.

The modal would have to have a fixed position for this to work.